# C dereferencing a pointer to array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have some code that looks like this:

```
int *array[10];

printf("%p\n", array); // Prints an address
printf("%p\n", *array); // Prints a different address
printf("%d\n", **array); // Segmentation Fault 11
printf("%d\n", *array[0]); // Segmentation Fault 11
printf("%d\n", (*array)[0]); // Segmentation Fault 11
```

Why do I get a segmentation fault? Shouldn't it print the first value in the first array?

Comment: That's not a pointer to an array; that's an array of ten pointers. (a) Use `%p` for printing pointer values, and (b) fixing that, the only line that does *not* invoke undefined behavior is the first printf. Everything relies on either evaluating, or dereferencing, indeterminate or invalid addresses.

Comment: an array of 10 int pointers

Comment: Also, `array` != `ages`, so work out a *real*, minimal code that is what you're *really* running.

Comment: Ohhhh, how would I declare a pointer to an array?

Comment: Why are you trying to `printf` pointers with `%d`??? `%d` is for `int` arguments, not for pointers.

Comment: Where is this "ages"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To take a closer look, understand the nature of the declaration:

```
int *array[10];
```

This declares an array of 10 pointers (currently uninitialized) to `int`s -- note that this is not the same as a pointer to an array of 10 ints, which would instead be declared `int (*array)[10]`.  Even declared this way though, you'd still need to initialize the pointer with something.

```
printf("%d\n", array); // Prints an address
```

This prints an the address of the ages array (the array is converted to a pointer automatically by passing it to printf).

```
printf("%d\n", *array); // Prints a different address
```

This uses the same rules to convert the array to a pointer, and then dereferences that pointer.  Therefore, you're printing the first value of the array (equivalent to `printf("%d\n", ages[0])`).  However, what you're actually printing here is an address, not an integer (even if it is uninitialized).

```
printf("%d\n", **array); // Segmentation Fault 11
printf("%d\n", *array[0]); // Segmentation Fault 11
printf("%d\n", (*array)[0]); // Segmentation Fault 11
```

Each of these are now dereferencing the uninitialized pointer stored in `array[0]`.  They do indeed be refer to an int, but the pointer to that int is whatever the compiler and/or your OS decided to put in there.

---

**Example: Pointer to an array**

An example of using a pointer to an array looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    int (*parr)[10] = &array;


    printf("%p\n", parr);
    printf("%p\n", *parr);
    printf("%d\n", **parr);
    printf("%d\n", *parr[0]);
    printf("%d\n", (*parr)[0]);
}
```

**Output** (addresses vary, obviously)

```
0x7fff5fbff990
0x7fff5fbff990
1
1
1
```

The last three all ultimately lead to the same element, but go about it in different ways.

Comment: Was about to post an answer and saw your explanation; just threw the sample code in yours instead. Tailor as you see fit.

Comment: Great answer! There's one thing that's still not clear. Why does parr and *parr print the same address? You're giving parr the address of the address of the first value in the array. Shouldn't they be different? @WhozCraig

Comment: C will automatically promote some types to other types in some situations.  One common case is promotion of an array to a pointer:  In short, if you pass an array directly to a function, it will behave as if you passed `*array` instead.  Therefore, you're passing the same pointer in both cases: once with an explicit dereference and once with an implicit dereference by the compiler.

Comment: @Zrax So what you are saying is that int (*parr)[10] = &array is the same as int (*parr)[10] = array?

Comment: @epiqueras the addresses are the same, but the *types* are different (the latter isn't valid C). It may not seem important, but it is *incredibly* so when you get to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You get a segmentation fault because you are attempting to dereference an uninitialized pointer, which is *Undefined Behavior*.

This command (and all following):

```
**ages
```

Dereferences the array (which decays to a pointer), which you then dereference. You have an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *array[10];
```

`array` is array[10] of pointer to int (note that `[]` has higher precedence than `*`). But none of these 10 pointers have been initialised to point to valid location.

Given that,

```
    printf("%d\n", array); // address of array itself (also address of first element)
    printf("%d\n", *array); // getting the value of the fisrt array element - UB/unitilialise (currently points to some random location)
    printf("%d\n", **array); // dereference that first pointer - UB/segfault as deferencing an initialised pointer
    printf("%d\n", *array[0]); // same as *array
    printf("%d\n", (*array)[0]); // same as **array
```

Comment: using value of `*array` is undefined behaviour too, since it is uninitialized.  (In addition to the UB caused by wrong printf format specifier)

Comment: @M.M yeah agree, that's `printf` UB

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        #include <math.h>
        #include <string.h> 

        int main() {


            int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

            int *p=arr;


            int intgerSize=sizeof(int);


            for(int k=0;k<5;k++)


            {  
                cout<<"arr ["<<k<<"] "<<*(p+(k*sizeof(int)/intgerSize));  
                cout<<"  "<<(p+(k*sizeof(int)/intgerSize));
                cout<<"  "<<p+k<<"\n"; 

            }`enter code here`

            return 0;
        }
OUTPUT:- 
arr [0] 1 0x7ffd180f5800  0x7ffd180f5800
arr [1] 2 0x7ffd180f5804  0x7ffd180f5804
arr [2] 3 0x7ffd180f5808  0x7ffd180f5808
arr [3] 4 0x7ffd180f580c  0x7ffd180f580c
arr [4] 5 0x7ffd180f5810  0x7ffd180f5810
```